# Can't Delete Empty Folder

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

On my Win 10 machine. It's an old folder from a google backup (not mine). I have it sitting on a secondary drive and I can't delete it. Here's what I know / have tried.

1. The folder name has a space in it. "Example  "
2. I can't rename, move, or open it. Access denied.
3. The security tab states "The request security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed."
4. Can't take ownership of the folder. Can't even view that info.
5. There are no handles or locks on the folder. It is not in use by any process.
6. CMD prompt delete or rename fails. Can't find the object.

Short of formatting the drive, I can't think of anything else I can do to remove this folder.

Comment: I've always used a little freeware app called [Move On Boot](https://emcosoftware.com/move-on-boot) for that kind of thing. Maybe worth a shot?

Comment: A chkdsk might be worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run (in an elevated shell) `icacls "Example "` to find out about the current permission cfg (you can also alter permissions with icacls)

Did you try `takeown /f "Example "`?